# Jquery Event Calendar with tool tip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, tooltip

Can somebody suggest me a good jquery calender with tooltip.

Comment: Yes. But StackOverflow isn't the place for this kind of question, try here: http://bit.ly/900913

Comment: The answer is: yes. Also - define 'good'.

Comment: I tried hard. But could not find a good one. Because every script I found has less than one issue. So I had to create my own using JqueryUI and poshytips. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the jQuery UI datepicker

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks lot for your help. I created my own, using Jquery UI and Poshytips.